# getting ids of divs in a loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

in my asp.net page when the button(getDivsOrder) is clicked, I want to get the ids of the divs in the mainDiv by order using a loop or something like that . How can I do that?

```
             <ContentTemplate>

              <div id="mainDiv"  runat="server">   
                  <div id="Red"     runat="server"></div> 
                  <div id="Yellow"  runat="server"></div>
                  <div id="Green"  runat="server"></div>
                  ...
              </div>

         <asp:Button ID="getDivsOrder" runat="server" Text="Update label " 
         onclick="btnHelloWorld_Click" />

         </ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: can you add the `btnHelloWorld_Click` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following utility method which you can put into a 'Utility Toolbelt' class or whatever. You would use it like: `mainDiv.FindControlsOfType<HtmlGenericControl>()` to return a list of controls.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a root Control, do a recursive search for Controls implementing or deriving from class/interface T
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="ctlRoot"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<T> FindControlsOfType<T>(this Control ctlRoot)
    {
        List<T> controlsFound = new List<T>();

        if (typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(ctlRoot))
            controlsFound.Add((T)(object)ctlRoot);

        foreach (Control ctlTemp in ctlRoot.Controls)
        {
            controlsFound.AddRange(FindControlsOfType<T>(ctlTemp));
        }

        return controlsFound;
    }
```

A problem you have is that `div` does not correspond to any standard ASP.NET web control, so `HtmlGenericControl` has to be used in the search. Therefore the search will pick up ANY `HtmlGenericControl`, not just `div` elements. Consequently, you will have to look at the `TagName` property of each control to ensure it's definitely a `div`.

Also, be aware that doing this at the server side will mean you are only checking the contents and order of the `mainDiv` controls *on the server*. If you are changing the order of the divs on the client side e.g. using jQuery draggable, the server won't know about it unless you use additional javascript to post back the new `div` order.

Comment: Please mark the question answered if this is now closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want div ids:

```
    foreach (Control c in mainDiv.Controls)
    {
        if (c is HtmlGenericControl)
        {
            String id = c.ID;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to change of the attributes of c as divs?

Comment: How do you mean? If you modify c you'll modify the corresponding div.